# Могут ли возникнуть дедлоки при использовании методов wait-notify?

Tags: java

Можете пожалуйста объяснить? Если нет, то почему, если да, то можно пример?

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/19908498/deadlocks-using-wait-and-notify

Comment: вопрос как-то ниочень. Ну допустим есть объекты `A` и `B`, поток `T1` делает `A.wait()`, а потом `B.notify()`, поток `T2` - `B.wait()` и `A.notify()`, все стоят, все ждут.

Answer (score 1):

По-сути, взаимная блокировка может возникнуть.

В коде, что ниже, нить не может продолжить выполнение, пока не выполнится определенное условие, а выполнится это условие может, если соседняя нить выполнит условие выхода из цикла while и разбудит текущую нить, что тоже не может выполнится потому, что соседняя нить ожидает изменения для выхода из своего цикла и пробуждения.

Может быть слишком надуманный пример.

Данный код у меня вызывает бесконечное ожидание нитей.

```
public class Solution {
private static boolean b1 = false;
private static boolean b2 = false;
private static final Object object = new Object();

public static void main(String[] args) {
    new Thread() {
        @Override
        public void run() {
            test1();
        }
    }.start();

    new Thread() {
        @Override
        public void run() {
            test2();
        }
    }.start();
}

private static void test1() {
    synchronized (object) {
        while (!b1) {
            try {
                object.wait();
            } catch (InterruptedException e) {
            }
        }
        b2 = true;
        object.notifyAll();
    }
}

private static void test2() {
    synchronized (object) {
        while (!b2) {
            try {
                object.wait();
            } catch (InterruptedException e) {
            }
        }
        b1 = true;
        object.notifyAll();
    }
}
}
```